# qt QTableWidget programattic select of cell - how to make ready with cursor in?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, selectionmodel

**Environment:**

- Qt 4.7.1
- Qt Creator 2.1.0
- c++

**Problem:**

I have a QTableWidget. I add a row, and then select the first cell.

What I want is to be able to immediately type into the cell after the program selects it, so I don't have to reach for the mouse.

The behavior of the select is to highlight the cell, not put a cursor in it. I have to click on the cell with the mouse before I can type.

Everything I've found so far to do with selection behavior has to do with row, column, or cell selection options; nothing about what the selection of a cell actually *does*.

Here's my code thus far, works as described; `rc` is the index to the last row, already determined:

```
ui->thetable->scrollToBottom();
QModelIndex index = ui->thetable->model()->index(rc, 0);
ui->thetable->selectionModel()->select(index,QItemSelectionModel::Select);
```

Comment: Try using [`setEditTriggers`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop) to trigger an edit whenever the current item changes. Something like this,`ui->thetable->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::CurrentChanged);`

Comment: @Mike But this would resolve in having always the cells in edit mode. Even if the user just selects the item it gets in edit mode. I think he wanted it to happen only if programmatically selected.

Comment: @luca-angioloni that's right; now if I could only get the tab order to behave after the programmed select -- the TAB key goes BACKWARDS one to the last of the previous line. So I enter the first data, then press TAB, _then_ I'm in the wrong cell. It works correctly (always TABS to the right / forward) if you mouse in instead of open editing via the program.

Comment: @fyngyrz that I wouldn't know... I didn't notice that behavior before

Comment: I ended up having to work around it all by manipulating only `QStringList` elements using external widgets, then setting up the table from those. It appears that several things in `QTableWidget` are broken in qt 4.7, and of course, the qt people have zero interest in making that release meet spec, so there's no point in trying to code to same. I got where I needed to get - the app is 100% functional, so onwards. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the edit method this way:

```
ui->thetable->edit(index);
```

using the index you already computed, or you could connect a custom signal of yours to `void QAbstractItemView::edit ( const QModelIndex & index )` slot inherited by QTableWidget's items.